# How we can enable socket testing Jmeter using script and run the test case?

Tags: jmeter

I have to test node socket.io code to send and receive a message on a particular port.

As I am reading about the JMeter tutorials they are saying we have to add plugin but when I try to add the plugin I am not able to find the option in my mac JMeter

Did anyone face the same issue?

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>        
<script>
    var socket = io('ws://127.0.0.1:3000');
    socket.emit('ui:index:loaded',{_id: '123456'});

    socket.on('app:banner:loaded',function(obj){
        console.log(obj);
    });

    socket.on('app:collection:loaded',function(obj){
        console.log(obj);
    });
</script>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you downloaded the plugin manager:-

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/

Once you download it, you will get an option to add plugins.

Please check.

I only have windows, so pardon me if this is some specific issue with Mac.

Comment: I downloaded the plugin but unable to find the option to add it ...... In macbook

Comment: After download put the downloaded jar in lib/ext of jmeter installation/extraction.Instructions:-Download the Plugins Manager JAR file and put it into JMeter's lib/ext directory. Then start JMeter and go to "Options" menu to access the Plugins Manager. Reference:-https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/...